# Talend - Send HTML table - Guarantee that we haven't Wrap Text

Tags: java, html, csv, html-email, talend

I'm using Talend Big Data Platform to send a CSV as HTML table by email. To build the HTML code I've a JavaRow with this:
c

```
ontext.MsgCode = "<br><br><style>table, td { white-space: nowrap;  border: 1px solid black;    border-collapse: collapse;}table, th { white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid black;}th, td { white-space: nowrap;},th {text-align: left;},th {background-color: #f2f2f2;},td{font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt;}</style> <table  white-space: nowrap;> <tr><th  white-space: nowrap;>warehouse</th><th  white-space: nowrap;>process</th><th  white-space: nowrap;>time</th><th>type</th><th>title</th><th  white-space: nowrap;>analysis</th></tr>";

context.TableRow = "</td><td>"+input_row.warehouse+"</td><td>"+input_row.process+"</td><td>"+input_row.time+"</td><td>"+input_row.type+"</td><td>"+input_row.title+"</td><td>"+input_row.analysis+"</td></tr>" + context.TableRow;

context.MsgCode = context.MsgCode + context.TableRow+ "</table>";
```

With this code my table is wrapping my columns and I get my columns names and the values cut in half.

What I want is to wrap text in order to fit the column width and to not have any cut off in cells.

What I am doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: What Email client are you using?  
You may find that the CSS is [unsupported](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/white-space/)

Comment: Yes, it is the Outlook :( Do I have any other option to get the wrap text without his CSS feature?

Comment: You might have more luck with the [word-wrap](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/word-wrap/) property. There are a few situational bugs but might be worth a shot!

Comment: I have found `word-break: break-all;` makes my life easy. Give it a go and see if it works for you as well

Comment: @Syfer I tried with word-break: break-all; and word-break: keep-all; but it didn't work. The column that I am trying this is a date: yyyy-MM-dd. I am not sure if the issue is on "-" character